# How to get the total sum of each column depending on the identified rows using MYSQL SELECT?

Tags: mysql

I'm a newbie to MYSQL queries. I have written the following code to get SUM of COL 11, COL 12, & COL 13 based on the data which are provided by the LIKE selection. Hope someone could be of help.

```
SELECT `COL 11`, `COL 12`, `COL 13`, SUM((`COL 11`), (`COL 12`), (`COL 13`)) FROM `samsungmobile_posts` WHERE `COL 2` LIKE '%S7%' OR '%S6%'
```

Comment: it is very unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to do this:

```
SELECT
  `COL 11`, `COL 12`, `COL 13`,
  `COL 11`+ `COL 12`+ `COL 13` total
FROM `samsungmobile_posts` WHERE `COL 2` LIKE '%S7%' OR  `COL 2` LIKE '%S6%'
```

Comment: I get all zeors when i take off %S7% and leave out only %S6%

`SELECT `COL 11`, `COL 12`, `COL 13`, `COL 11`+ `COL 12`+ `COL 13` total FROM `samsungmobile_posts` WHERE `COL 2` LIKE '%S6%'`

Comment: Can tell me how you could query the same data based on different date points. For example, 

Between, 12-12-2015 to 12-05-2016 & 12-12-2016 to 12-05-2017. and also show the date as well in a row? 
I require 5 date points as rows and corresponding totals

Thank you.

Comment: You can use an OR between the two filters - like `col between d1 and d2 or col between d3 and d4`

Comment: Im sorry but I'm unable to figure out the code. Just to be clear the table would should look like this, 

|Date            | COL 11| COL 12| COL 13|
|02- 12-2015|  SUM   | SUM     | SUM    |
|02- 01-2016|  SUM   | SUM     | SUM    |
|02- 08-2017|  SUM   | SUM     | SUM    |     

Thank you.

Comment: @John please ask a new question as it seems like an unrelated to this question